# MySQL - Skip column in index

Tags: mysql, database

We have a (big) table with a multiple-column index on columns A, B and C.
Now we want to do a query with the following format:
 `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (B=... AND C=...) OR (B=... AND C=...) OR ...`
Because there are many rows in the table, and no index is used, the performance of the query is very bad.

An index with columns B, C would have been ideal, unfortunately it's not available, and we cannot change it as well (other vendor). Column A has a value where we are not interested in.

To let MySQL use the available index, we have added an extra condition in the WHERE: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 99, 100)) ((B=... AND C=...) OR (B=... AND C=...))OR ...`. The result is that now the index is properly used, and the query performance is already a lot better. However it looks a bit ugly to provide all possible values of A in the query. My feeling is that there should be an easier way to do the same, or with even a better performance.

Is there a way to force MySQL to use the index, even when column A is not used in the query? Or have we already found the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, might work!

[MySQL index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

Basically say `FROM table USE INDEX (index_name)` or `FROM table FORCE INDEX (index_name)`

But that won't help, because basically if you force an INDEX, it's back to doing a full table scan.

Try instead

```
FROM table
WHERE A IN (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM table) 
AND ....
```

Might be cleaner

Comment: Sorry, wasn't done with my answer, Wanted to say it won't work !!! and testing out cleaner version